# Which tags are not in the database?

Tags: sql, mysql

Given a collection of user specified tags how do I determine which ones **are not** in the tags table with 1 SQL Statement?

Assuming a table schema `tags (id, tag)` and I'm using mysql, if there's an optimization I'm unaware of.

thanks

Comment: Turns out you can't do it with 1 query :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  Tag
FROM    UserSpecifiedTags
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AllTags ON UserSpecifiedTags.Tag = AllTags.Tag
WHERE   AllTags.Tag IS NULL
```

This should return what you want. In my experience, executing a join and looking for rows which don't have a match is **much** quicker than using the `IN` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from canonical_list_of_tags where tag not in (select tag from used_tags)
```

At least that works in T-SQL for SQL Server ...

**Edit:** Assuming that the table `canonical_list_of_tags` is populated with the result of "*Given a collection of user specified tags*"

Comment: Cannonical_list_of_tags needs to be a pre-existing table for this to work...?

Do I need to empty the table and then insert the user provided tags for this to work?  Seems like it's be slower than just iterating over the tags individually?  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Not sure what structures you have in MySQL, but SQL in the middle of loops should be converted into a single sql if possible. Consider a simple case, the table is so small it fits on one block. If you to LOOP/QUERY you'll read that same block over and over and over.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    utt.tagName
from
    userTypedTags utt
    left join tag t on utt.tagName = t.tag
where
    t.ID is null
    and utt.userID = <ID of the User in question>
```

That is assuming that you have table

```
userTypedTags(userID, tagName)
```

I have added a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-records)